# How to modify a list of lists if it contains x or -x?

Tags: list, ocaml, nested-lists

I'm trying to modify a list of lists with certain conditions, if a nested list contains x, I'd like to remove that list from the list, if a nested list contains -x, I'd like to remove -x from that list while still keeping the said list. Finally, if the nested list doesn't contain x or -x, I'd keep it.

So far this is what I've tried, I don't really get why it doesn't work as intented...

```ml
let rec simplify i clauses =
  match clauses with
  | [] -> []
  | x::y -> 
      if (List.mem i x) then 
        [] @ simplify i y 
      else if (List.mem (-i) x) then 
        List.filter (fun x -> x != -i) x @ simplify i y 
      else 
        [x];;
```

The expected results would be that:

```ml
simplify (-1) [[-1;2];[-1;7];[-2;1];[-2;3];[-3;2];[-3;4];[-4;5];[-4;15];[-5;2];[-5;4];[-6;5];[-7;1];[-7;8];[-7;6];[-8;7];[-8;9];[-8;10];[-9;8];[-10;8];[-10;11];[-10;12];[-11;9];[-11;10];[-12;6];[-12;10];[-12;13];[-12;15];[-13;11];[-14;13];[-14;15];[-15;12];[1];[-14]]
;;
- : int list list =
[[-14]; []; [-15; 12]; [-14; 15]; [-14; 13]; [-13; 11]; [-12; 15]; [-12; 13];
 [-12; 10]; [-12; 6]; [-11; 10]; [-11; 9]; [-10; 12]; [-10; 11]; [-10; 8];
 [-9; 8]; [-8; 10]; [-8; 9]; [-8; 7]; [-7; 6]; [-7; 8]; [-7]; [-6; 5]; 
 [-5; 4]; [-5; 2]; [-4; 15]; [-4; 5]; [-3; 4]; [-3; 2]; [-2; 3]; [-2]]
```

Whereas the actual results are:

```ml
simplifie_aux (-1) [[-1;2];[-1;7];[-2;1];[-2;3];[-3;2];[-3;4];[-4;5];[-4;15];[-5;2];[-5;4];[-6;5];[-7;1];[-7;8];[-7;6];[-8;7];[-8;9];[-8;10];[-9;8];[-10;8];[-10;11];[-10;12];[-11;9];[-11;10];[-12;6];[-12;10];[-12;13];[-12;15];[-13;11];[-14;13];[-14;15];[-15;12];[1];[-14]]
;;
- : int list list = [[-2]; [-2; 3]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it appears you should be recursing in the final `else [x]` case as well.  I would rewrite it as a `fold`, however, since you are dropping (some) empty lists from your expected output, eg.

```
let simplify i clauses = 
  let f acc lst =
    if List.mem i lst then acc
    else [List.filter (fun x -> x != -i) lst] @ acc
  in List.fold_left f [] clauses

(* - : int list list =
   [[-14]; []; [-15; 12]; [-14; 15]; ... ] *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Results are much better with a recursive call in the else. Although I'm not familiar with ```fold_left``` yet, what shoud I modify in my function in order not to drop the empty list I'd need to have ? Because I thought my ```if (List.mem i x) then [] @ simplify i y``` was the part where I'd add an empty list where there's ```i``` in it.

Comment: do you mean, you would want `[-1;2]` to be `[]` in your result?

Comment: exactly yes. If ```i``` exists in a list, I remove it and have it replaced by ```[]```, if ```-i``` exists in a list, I only remove ```-i``` from that list, but still keep it. Sorry if some points are unclear, English isn't my first language.

Comment: in that case you could append an empty list, `[[]]`, which you could cons instead `[] :: ...` (also fixing the types in your other branches)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your code is working very hard to do something very straightforward.

```
let simplify i lst =
  lst
  |> List.filter 
     @@ List.for_all 
     @@ fun x -> x <> i && x <> -i
```

By using `List.for_all` rather than two calls to `List.mem` (one for `i` and one for `-i`) we avoid unnecessary traversals of the sublists.